# Hooking Android method with Frida but .implementation() not executed

Tags: android, hook, frida

I am learning Frida, and trying to hook a method `checkFlag` and trying to modify the boolean flag from true to false.

Below is my `demo app code`

[image]

In normal scenario, the Toast with `Flag is True` is displayed. I want to hook the `checkFlag` method and modify `flag` value to `false` so that `Warning! Flag is compromised` is displayed. I am first trying to make sure the method is hooked by simply adding a log entry but I suppose the `.implementation` is not being executed at all.

Below is my Frida snippet:

```
import frida


device = frida.get_usb_device()
pid = device.spawn(["com.example.hookme"])
device.resume(pid)
import time
time.sleep(1)
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script('''
Java.perform(function() {
    console.log("Running Script -- ");
    var MainActivity = Java.use('com.example.hookme.MainActivity');

    console.log(MainActivity);

    MainActivity.checkFlag.implementation = function(x) { // x is the "flag" param

        // change the value of x to False, so that else condition is fired. 

        console.log("Inside checkFlag Implementation.");
    }
    console.log("Post Implementation");

});
''')
script.load()
```

After running the script, the app spawns perfectly but the method is not hooked. Meaning I cannot see the log implemented inside `MainActivity.checkFlag.implementation...`

[image]

Can anyone please point out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that when your hooking code is installed the `MainActivity.onCreate()` method has already been called and thus your hook is never called.

The reason for this is that your python code first calls `device.resume(pid)` later `device.attach(pid)` and the code for loading the Frida JavaScript.

When you want to perform early instrumentation  e.g. to hook something in the code that is executed when the app starts you have to first attach to the app and load your Frida JavaScript code and then resume the app process.

This way Frida has a chance to hook the `checkFlag` method before it has been called the one and only time.

```
device = frida.get_usb_device()
pid = device.spawn(["com.example.hookme"])
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script('''
Java.perform(function() {
    ....
}
''')
script.load()
device.resume(pid)
```